In Visual Studio (ideally) I want to split and insert text into a string
Using Visual Studio 2022 Professional, I want want to replace and insert some text strings into another text string. Include the bit after the underscore as well. Some examples:
Before:
CanCallGet()
CanCallFetch()
CanCallDelete()
CanCall_Delete2()
CanCallPush()
CanCall_Push2()
After:
CanCall_Get()
CanCall_Fetch()
CanCall_Delete()
CanCall_Delete2()
CanCall_Push()
CanCall_Push2()
I have tried the Regular Expression (CanCall)[A-Z]
However, the issue is that I do not know if I can carry the matching wildcard portion (A-Z) to concatenate with the underscore and matched value.
There can be any number of matching letters for the wildcard, including A to Z.
How do I get this to work in one step?

Search for CanCall, replace with CanCall_. Works fine for me in RegexBuddy, and produces the exact output you want.

No the idea was to match with anything after the CanCall and replace with CanCall_ and then the match.  As per the other answer.

As I said, it works perfectly with your sample text, and produces exactly the output that you want. Did you bother to try it?

Sorry but I have extended the question to clarify that I wanted to be able to run it again and handle already processed methods, without coming up with two underscores.

Not sure if I understood correctly but doesn't this work?
Find: (CanCall)([A-Za-z]*)(\(\))
Replace: $1_$2$3

That's perfect! Thank you! I didn't know you could add those dollar bits to the replace text. What are they called?

In my answer (CanCall) is a "capture group" and $1 is the "replacement pattern". See also e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#capture-groups-and-replacement-patterns

I wanted to be able to run it again and still end up with a single underscore.  Do you know how I would do that?

What about this:
var text = "CanCallGet()";
var temp = text.Split("CanCall");
var result = "CanCall" + "_" + temp[1];


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

That is not a RegEx. (Regular Expression)
